# test-js: scientific software: significant figures

Tags: floating-point, jestjs, precision, floating-accuracy, significant-digits

I am attempting to test scientific software written in TypeScript using Jest.

I want to test all my floating point results to 8 significant figures, but it seems the only test method available in ts-jest, "toBeCloseTo", works on matching figures after the decimal point in decimal notation.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobeclosetonumber-numdigits

The scientific and engineering community works to significant figures, rather than numbers after the decimal point.  **Have I overlooked some functionality.  If not, is there a plan to add it?**

In the meantime, I have a workaround which would only work for numbers where the significant figures after the decimal point in decimal notation are within the range of the significant figures required in scientific notation.

```
test("MyFunction", () =>{
    let sigAfterDecimal = SIG_FIG - Math.floor((Math.log(ExpectedResult)/Math.log(10)));
    expect(IF97_B23T(functionInput)).toBeCloseTo(SigAfterDecimal, thisTestAccuracy);
});
```

But this wouldn't work for checking eg. the Avogadro constant, 6.02214076×10^23 to 8 significant figures, as none of the relevant significant figures appear after the decimal point in decimal notation.

Comment: Hi there, not into this suject, but isn't it an option to mulitply your float with a 10*8 and then round it to see if it is accurate? I think the reason `toBecloseTo` exists because floats are hard to test, certainly in JS. Its a guess..

Comment: Further limit `Math.log(ExpectedResult)` trouble when `ExpectedResult <= 0.0`

Comment: Note: `6.02214076×10^23` has 9 significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've had a go myself and have created a pull request to the main facebook/jest team to include my fork "float_sig_fig"   which adds toBeCloseToSigFig which that the powers in normalized scientific notation are the same and that the mantissas match to a required number of significant figures.  Thanks to Chux I made sure the log(0) case is covered.

It would be my first source contribution to an open source software project if it is accepted.

Comment: Message from the favebook/jest maintainer:Thanks for the PR! Unfortunately, we don't really accept new matchers at this time. I suggest you open a PR at jest-extended [link](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended) instead